# Can't figure out how to replace these MR16 GU5.3 bulbs

Tags: light, bulb, lamp

I've replaced most of the MR16 bulbs in my house as they have a simple clip system but I can't figure these out. This bathroom has MR16 bulbs that go quite far into the ceiling and are different again.

[image]

Edit: The bulbs I have managed to replace are now LED and emit very low buzz - is there any way around this or should I just switch back to halogen

Comment: Does the whole assembly pull out of the ceiling allowing you to remove it from the backside?

Comment: I'm not sure how that would be done? Forcefully pulling down?

Answer (score 1):

The MU16 connectors are a twist type, turn counterclockwise to remove. They often need some effort to turn. There isn't anything physically stopping it from turning other than 
friction

The buzzing is either from a dimmer, a bad bulb or electromagnetic (EM) interference. Remove the dimmer if there is one. Verify that the bulb is good. Test for EM interference from other devices by turning off devices in the home until you find the offending item.

[image]

Picture: lightbulbwholesaler.com

Comment: On last comment is Gu10, mr16 is only 12v
GU10 220V